# Override the column header by the 1st row of a c# datatable

Tags: c#, datatable, header, console-application

I am wondering if there exist an *efficient* way to override the `column` headers of a `datatable` by its first `row`

To illustrate my point, assuming one has, as a sample `datatable`

`Column 0 Column 1  Column 2`

`--------------------------`

`x1        x2        x3`

As as matter of fact, it can be can used

`dataTable.Columns["Column 0"].ColumnName = "x1"`;

`dataTable.Columns["Column 1"].ColumnName = "x2"`; etc.

`dataTable.AcceptChanges()`;

However this manual update becomes undeniably inefficient if one deals with `50` or `100`  `headers`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: Alright, a edit has been performed and the target is a `c# console app`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Data;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Your code goes here
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
            table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
            //table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

            // Here we add five DataRows.
            table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David");
            table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam");
            table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff");
            table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet");
            table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie");
            if(table.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++){
                    string columnName = Convert.ToString(table.Columns[i]);
                    table.Columns[columnName].ColumnName = Convert.ToString(table.Rows[0][i]);
                }
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++){
                Console.WriteLine(table.Columns[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, `Serhat Oz`.